# Button onclick works fine but undesired behavior when pressing enter to submit form

Tags: javascript, dom, forms

I'm not sure if I need a form for this, it's a javascript that takes an input from a textbox, does some calculation on it, and displays the results in a div. I just want the user to be able to submit by clicking submit or by pressing enter.

In short, if the button type is "button", clicking works fine but pressing enter works strangely, and if the button type is "submit", pressing enter works fine, but clicking works strangely. Below is a sample of the code (removed some business logic and other variables that were working fine to make it simpler to display here):

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="calcserial()">
Serial no: <input type="text" name="serialno" id="serialno" /><br />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="calcserial()" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function calcserial(){  

var x=document.getElementById('serialno').value;

var year=[business logic];
var month=[business logic];

document.getElementById('results').innerHTML="Shipped: " + month + ", " + year;  
} 
</script>

<div id=results></div>
```

To give more detail about the strange behavior, when input type is "button" and I press enter, rather than running the calcserial() function, the textbox is cleared and the url is changed to:

```
[filename].php?serialno=[value]#
```

With [value] being what ever was in the text box. Then, if I put in the same exact value again and press enter again, it works as intended, but only if the url already shows the value I am submitting. If I enter a different value, the text box is cleared again and the url is changed to show the new value. If I switch the input type to "submit", the problem is resolved for pressing enter, but the same problem then occurs when clicking the button to submit.

Why is this happening? Any ideas how to resolve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

`<form action="#" onsubmit="calcserial()">`

To this:

`<form action="#" onsubmit="calcserial();return false;">`

That should stop the default action that would normally happen on submit of a form, which in your case with `action="#"` results in the same page being reloaded.

Given that you don't actually want to submit anything (to the webserver) you don't really need a form for this. An `<input type="button">` plus checking for enter `onkeyup` of the text input could achieve the same effect.

Comment: Thanks!! return false worked, so I am happy leaving the code how it is... but, would there be any advantage to removing the form and checking for enter onkeyup like your other suggestion?

Comment: A form is convenient as it provides a container for form controls and makes access easier. They also provide a fall back if script is disabled or fails to execute.

Comment: Well I only mentioned it because you started out your question saying you weren't sure if you needed a form. The answer is no, you don't _need_ it, but I'm not sure that there is any special advantage to removing it. If you later decide that your calculation should happen server-side you'll already have the form there ready to go. Note for future reference: if you change the event handler in the form to be `onsubmit="return calcserial();"` then in your `calcserial()` function you can decide whether to return true or false meaning do or don't continue with submitting the form.